# React Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I found shouldDidUpdate's performance worse than refs control update。
CODE：

```
//A： shoudDidUpdate control udpate

import React, {Component, PropTypes, cloneElement} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Level1 extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        let {rows, columns}=this.props;

        return <div>
            {rows.map((row, idx) => {
                return <Level2 key={idx} row={row} columns={columns} ref={`row_${idx}`}/>
            })}
        </div>
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.rows !== this.props.rows
            || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns;
    }
}

class Level2 extends Component {
    render() {
        let {row, columns}  = this.props;
        return <div>
            <Level3 row={row} key="level2" ref="row" columns={columns}/>
        </div>
    }


    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.row !== this.props.row
            || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns;
    }
}
class Level3 extends Component {
    render() {
        let {row, columns} = this.props;
        return <div columns={columns} row={row}>
            {columns.map((column, i) => {
                return <Level4 ref={column} value={row[column]} key={i}/>
            })}
        </div>
    }


    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return (nextProps.row !== this.props.row
        || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns);
    }
}

class Level4 extends Component {
    render() {
        let {value} = this.props;
        this.value = value;
        return <span className="cell" ref="columnValue">
            {value}
        </span>
    }


    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.value !== this.props.value;
    }
}

function getData(cIndex = "C",
                 vIndex = "V") {
    let rows = [],
        columns = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        columns.push(`${cIndex}${i}`);
    }

    for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
        let rowData = {};
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            rowData[column] = `${vIndex}${row}_${column}`;
        })
        rows.push(rowData)
    }
    return {rows: rows, columns: columns};
}

var __ret = getData();
var rows = __ret.rows;
var columns = __ret.columns;

ReactDOM.render(<Level1 rows={rows} columns={columns}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
console.time("a")

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var __ret = getData("C", "b" + i);
    var rows = __ret.rows;

    ReactDOM.render(<Level1 rows={rows} columns={columns}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
}
console.timeEnd("a")


//B: this.refs.update control update


import React, {Component, PropTypes, cloneElement} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Level1 extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        let {rows, columns}=this.props;

        return <div>
            {rows.map((row, idx) => {
                return <Level2 key={idx} row={row} columns={columns} ref={`row_${idx}`}/>
            })}
        </div>
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        this.preRows = this.props.rows;
        // console.info("l1",nextProps.rows !== this.props.rows
        //     || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns);
        return nextProps.rows !== this.props.rows
            || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns;
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        let {rows, columns}=this.props;
        rows.forEach((row, idx) => {
            this.refs[`row_${idx}`].update(row, columns);
        });
    }

}


class Level2 extends Component {
    render() {
        let {row, columns}  = this.props;
        this.row = row;
        this.columns = columns;
        return <div>
            <Level3 row={row} key="level2" ref="row" columns={columns}/>
        </div>
    }

    update(row, columns) {
        if (row !== this.row || columns !== this.columns) {
            this.refs.row.update(row, columns);
            this.row = row;
            this.columns = columns;
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        // console.info("l2",nextProps.rows !== this.props.rows
        //     || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns);

        return this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns;
    }
}
class Level3 extends Component {
    render() {
        let {row, columns} = this.props;
        this.row = row;
        this.columns = columns;
        return <div>
            {columns.map((column, i) => {
                return <Level4 ref={column} value={row[column]} key={i}/>
            })}
        </div>
    }


    update(row, columns) {
        if (row !== this.row || columns !== this.columns) {

            columns.forEach((column) => {
                this.refs[column].update(row[column]);
            });
            this.row = row;
            this.columns = columns;
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        // console.info("l3",nextProps.row !== this.props.row
        //     || this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns);
        return this.props.columns !== nextProps.columns;
    }
}
class Level4 extends Component {
    render() {
        let {value} = this.props;
        this.value = value;
        return <span className="cell" ref="columnValue">
            {value}
        </span>
    }

    update(value) {
        if (value !== this.value) {
            this.refs.columnValue.innerHTML = value;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        // console.info("l4",nextProps.value !== this.props.value);
        return false;
    }
}

function getData(cIndex = "C",
                 vIndex = "V") {
    let rows = [],
        columns = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        columns.push(`${cIndex}${i}`);
    }

    for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
        let rowData = {};
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            rowData[column] = `${vIndex}${row}_${column}`;
        })
        rows.push(rowData)
    }
    return {rows: rows, columns: columns};
}

var __ret = getData();
var rows = __ret.rows;
var columns = __ret.columns;

ReactDOM.render(<Level1 rows={rows} columns={columns}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
console.time("a")

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var __ret = getData("C", "b" + i);
    var rows = __ret.rows;

    ReactDOM.render(<Level1 rows={rows} columns={columns}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
}
console.timeEnd("a")
```

My Computer : macbook pro 2.8Ghz i7 memory 16GB
Browser : chrom 56
A： 260 - 300 ms
B: 30 ms

Browser: IE 11
A: 1000-1100ms
B: 500-630ms
Is there a better way to deal with such a scenario?

The scenario for this example is to update the entire list of data at a time. So, 'shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
         Return nextProps.rows! == this.props.rows
             || this.props.columns! == nextProps.columns;
     } ', Which returns true every time. This is not wrong.
The key point is that the implementation of B program does not have to be executed each time, shouldComponentUpdate the call stack. I think there is a better way to solve this problem.